# std::visit on std::variant does not work as I expect

Tags: c++, c++17

Given the following (pared down to essentials):

```
#include <memory>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

struct Cell;

using Expression =
    std::variant<std::string, std::shared_ptr<Cell>, std::nullptr_t>;

struct Cell {
    explicit Cell(Expression car, Expression cdr) : car_{car}, cdr_{cdr} {
    }

    Expression car_;
    Expression cdr_;
};
```

I wanted to create an output iterator for Expressions.  My first attempt looked like this:

```
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Expression& exp) {
     switch (exp.index()) {
         case 0:
             out << std::get<0>(exp);
             break;
         case 1: {
                 auto cell = std::get<1>(exp);
                 out << "( " << cell->car_ << " . " << cell->cdr_ << " )";
             }
             break;
         case 2:
             out << "()";
             break;
     }

     return out;
 }
```

This worked but I thought I could do better (more readable, more maintainable etc.) so I came up with this.

```
struct ExpressionOutputVisitor {
    std::ostream& out_;

    ExpressionOutputVisitor(std::ostream& out) : out_{out} {
    }

    void operator()(std::string& arg) const {
        out_ << arg << '\n';
    }

    void operator()(std::shared_ptr<Cell>& arg) const {
        out_ << "( " << arg->car_ << " . " << arg->cdr_ << " )"; // error at arg->car_
    }

    void operator()(std::nullptr_t) const {
        out << "()";
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Expression& exp) {
    std::visit(ExpressionOutputVisitor{out}, exp);
    return out;
}
```

...however this second version does not work and I am perplexed as to why not.  The error from the compiler (clang++ 6.0.0 on Linux) is:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
      ('basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >' and 'Expression' (aka
      'variant<basic_string<char>, shared_ptr<Cell>, nullptr_t>'))
        out_ << "(" << arg->car_ << " " << arg->cdr_ << ")";
        ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~
```

followed by the usual couple of pages of spewage.  I've also tried with g++ 7.3.0 with the same problem except even more error output.  Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first version is self-recursive.  Since the function is known in its own body, this works without issue.

The second version has multiple mutually-recursive functions.  You'll need a forward declaration of the one that's used before it is defined.

Add the line

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Expression& exp);
```

before `struct ExpressionOutputVisitor { ... };`

The failure relates to point-of-declaration, and has nothing to do with `std::visit` or `std::variant`.

Comment: Thanks.  I had suspected it might be something like that but declared the operator() for shared_ptr<Cell> instead which didn't work.